# Firefox can access internet but terminal can't

Tags: networking, apt, firefox, proxy

I'm connected to university router, and I know they have many restrictions, but firefox is accessing the repo links without any issue, but the terminal can't.
How can I make the terminal use the same protocol as firefox?
My Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS
Also, the ubuntu software package manager looks like it could work, since i could start the installation of VLC but never crossed 6-8%, i get timeouts everytime.
I tried using Synaptic, but same 403 Forbidden.
I tried using Proxies, tunnel my connexion through ssh from my phone, but the package manager (apt or synaptic) don't pass the authentication phase.
Also, i know the university is using fortiguard, but as i said, i can access all remote repo with firefox.

```
wadaane@wadaane-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:2 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:3 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:4 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

EDIT:
Here is the truncated output from tcpdump:

```
22:15:22.144893 IP wadaane-ubuntu.32779 > 172.18.3.2.domain: 62851+ [1au] PTR? 23.91.189.91.in-addr.arpa. (54)
22:15:22.152815 IP 172.18.3.2.domain > wadaane-ubuntu.32779: 62851 1/0/1 PTR economy.canonical.com. (89)

22:15:22.144309 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [S], seq 704597193, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2654335473 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:15:22.152697 IP economy.canonical.com.http > wadaane-ubuntu.36120: Flags [S.], seq 2352942977, ack 704597194, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 746784843 ecr 2654335473,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:15:22.152765 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2654335482 ecr 746784843], length
22:15:22.153117 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:160, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2654335482 ecr 746784843], length 159: HTTP: GET /ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease HTTP/1.1
22:15:22.168911 IP economy.canonical.com.http > wadaane-ubuntu.36120: Flags [P.], seq 1:1449, ack 160, win 5792, options [nop,nop,TS val 746784843 ecr 2654335482], length 1448: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
22:15:22.168951 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [.], ack 1449, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 2654335498 ecr 746784843], length 0
22:15:22.169724 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [F.], seq 160, ack 1449, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 2654335499 ecr 746784843], length 0
22:15:22.178134 IP economy.canonical.com.http > wadaane-ubuntu.36120: Flags [P.], seq 1449:2897, ack 160, win 5792, options [nop,nop,TS val 746784843 ecr 2654335482], length 1448: HTTP
22:15:22.178177 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [R], seq 704597353, win 0, length 0
22:15:22.179030 IP economy.canonical.com.http > wadaane-ubuntu.36120: Flags [FP.], seq 2897:2912, ack 160, win 5792, options [nop,nop,TS val 746784843 ecr 2654335482], length 15: HTTP
22:15:22.179049 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [R], seq 704597353, win 0, length 0
22:15:22.185000 IP economy.canonical.com.http > wadaane-ubuntu.36120: Flags [.], ack 161, win 5792, options [nop,nop,TS val 746784843 ecr 2654335499], length 0
22:15:22.185182 IP wadaane-ubuntu.36120 > economy.canonical.com.http: Flags [R], seq 704597354, win 0, length 0
```

Comment: Are you using raspberry since I can see [identical question posted by you on Raspberry Pi - Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91808/ubuntu-firefox-can-access-internet-but-terminal-cant)?

Comment: That was a mistake ... but i still got the same probleme on raspbian

Comment: Have you tried updating using other network than University's network? If you are using Raspbian, the question might be closed as off-topic. Also, instead of Syria server try to use other server like main, UK, India, USA, etc.

Comment: I tried us and uk, and im not on raspbian anymore, this is  on my laptop

Comment: I strongly recommend you to either try other network or a VPN (proxy) since it doesn't seem to be system issue but a network issue.

Comment: Under the VPN, proxy, i get the same thing, Firefox connects, but apt doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86906/discussion-between-kulfy-and-wadaane).

Comment: Did you try to figure out if Firefox is using a proxy, and if so configure that same proxy in a terminal session by setting the `http_proxy` environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the network problem couldn't be solved, as most said, its an IT departement thing.
So the final solution is to use apt-offline.

Comment: I was going to suggest talking to the University Staff to see what could be done for better support. Ubuntu could be beneficial to many University students and the country as a whole. Then I read your answer before posting the comment under your question. Don't forget to accept your answer as the correct one by clicking the grey check mark next to it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the existing packages and then try the following:

```
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get clean
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
```